# Why does the generated NinjectMVC3.cs from NuPack not compile? (or what happened to MvcServiceLocator in ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta? )

Tags: ninject, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

Using the NuPack addin and installing the NInject MVC 3 package results in the following compile error in the generated `NinjectMVC3.cs` file.

`The name 'MvcServiceLocator' does not exist in the current context`

The [sample video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FKJ2Au27gQ) David Ebbo posted shows it [working just fine at 09:43](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FKJ2Au27gQ#t=9m43s).

Here is the currently generated class:

```
public class NinjectMVC3 {
    public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
        //kernel.Bind<IThingRepository>().To<SqlThingRepository>();
    }

    public static void SetupDependencyInjection() {
        // Create Ninject DI Kernel 
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // Register services with our Ninject DI Container
        RegisterServices(kernel);

        // Tell ASP.NET MVC 3 to use our Ninject DI Container 
        MvcServiceLocator.SetCurrent(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, `MvcServiceLocator` has gone away. Whenever the video was made there was a mismatch in versions, I guess.

There are excellent explanations available [here](http://www.userinexperience.com/post/Upgrading-Your-MVC3-Application-from-Preview-1-to-Beta.aspx) and [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+BradWilson+(Brad+Wilson)).

The two steps that will make Ninject work are as follows. Replace `NinjectMVC3` with the following (I also changed the name which isn't necessary):

```
public class NinjectResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private static IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterServices(kernel);
    }

    public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //kernel.Bind<IThingRepository>().To<SqlThingRepository>();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

and add the following line to `App_Start()` in `gloabl.asax.cs`

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectResolver());
```

Comment: Yep! The NuPack package was based on MVC 3 Preview 1 and needs to be updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed the package and uploaded it to the feed.  It would be great if you had a chance to try it and verify that it works now.  I upped the version of Ninject.MVC3 from 0.1 to 0.2 :)

Comment: Should both versions Ninject.MVC (0.1 and 0.2) appear in the Add Package Reference GUI? The new one (0.2) definitely builds as expected.

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  The UI is still in a very early shape.  It's more or less just a prototype.

Comment: Actually, it compiled, but trying to run the code, I get Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.IMvcServiceLocator' from assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: I suspect you may have some old binaries that got left in your bin folder, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed Ninject.MVC3 0.3. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta.

I've added this code into my `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
    public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<SqlProductRepository>();
    }

    public void SetupDependencyInjection()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Ninject.Mvc3.NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
    }
```

And I've added a call to `SetupDependencyInjection()` into `Application_Start()` function so it looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        SetupDependencyInjection();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The `IProductRepository` and `SqlProductRepository` are classes that I made in my Models folder and I've added a constructor dependency to my `HomeController`. Here's the code:

```
    private IProductRepository products;

    public HomeController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        products = productRepository;
    }
```

I've added some breakpoints and ran the application and it works like a charm. Hope this helps.